# Meaning of "terms were too equal"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the phrase below?

> The battle was not of long duration. The terms were too equal to leave the issue long in doubt.

Can you explain the meaning of "The terms were too equal" in this context?

Source: *Belle Boyd in Camp and Prison*, 1865, p. 252. The book is about the American Civil War.

Comment: Please provide more context. Why there was a battle, and what the battle was over?

Comment: @Man_From_India It's the [Second Battle of Winchester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Battle_of_Winchester) in which Confederate forces drove Union forces out of Winchester and scattered them in the pursuit.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks I found it :-) I am unaware of this history. Read the two pages of the book where the quoted sentence is written, pretty good narration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good guess:

The *terms* of a battle are the conditions which each opposing side has to deal with, besides things they control.  Obviously one side would like to make the other side have terms that make it more difficult for them to fight.

Usually one side does not know all the "terms" that can affect the other side.  So the outcome of any given battle, even if there is a difference in the number of men, weaponry, etc. is not perfectly predictable.

What the sentence is saying is that the terms were known, so in that case the side with more men, weapons, and other visible attributes was certain to win.  There was no unpredictability in the battle.

Comment: +1 for your explanation of *terms*. But I think *terms were too equal* is a misprint. 1) "too equal" implies a doubtful result, not a certain one. 2) In fact, Ewell commanded an entire corps, some 19,000 men, against Milroy's 6,900, and had Milroy's position virtually surrounded. It looks to me like Miss Boyd meant *terms were too **unequal***.

Comment: Thank you, StoneyB. Those "too equal terms" really confused me.